# Memory foot print goes up 10 folds when apache camel is split objects

Tags: performance, memory-management, apache-camel

I have a camel route wherein number of split objects may go as high as 90k. Since the number of tokens which can be found in the XML as be as high as 90k. My initial file size is around 40 MB but during the splitting of the file the memory footprint goes as high as 600MB.

```
 .split(body().convertTo(String.class)
              .tokenizeXML(dummy value,dummy value), new DummyAggregator())
 .streaming()
 .convertBodyTo(Document.class)
 .bean(DummyTransformer.class, TRANSFORM)
 .end()
```

Any help to optimize this code is a huge help.

Comment: I'm wondering how you're measuring memory foot print. And how do you know that memory usage spikes during the split?

Comment: I see the memory spike when the program starts reading the file and i am suspecting this part of the code Let me know if you think otherwise

Comment: The convert to String will read the file into memory, so if its a big file then that takes up some memory, you likely dont need to do that as the splitter should be able to read the file in chunks via streaming mode. Also depends a bit what you do in the dummy aggregator how much memory that uses.